# What is pseudo code of maxent classifier for NER?

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am building a Named Entity Recognizer with a Maximum Entropy and am looking for two things:

1) what is meant by features?

2) how features will extract from training data set?

Comment: go through OpenNLP NameFinder source code. It will be helpful for you.